# Embeddings of vector spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space.  Is the space of embeddings
$$
\coprod_1^{k} V \to V
$$
path connected for large enough $n$?  Clearly $n=1$ is not enough, but I feel like $n=2$ is enough for $1$-connected.  Does the space become highly connected as $n\to \infty$?  This feels like it is equivalent to a question about the little disks operads, but I don't know how to frame it as such.

Comment: Do you mean embeddings as topological spaces?  If so, do you mean proper embeddings?  My guess is the answers are Yes and No, since you mentioned the little disks operad.

Comment: Smooth embeddings as manifolds.  Proper I'm not sure...

Comment: No not proper, just smooth.  I think the answer below is what I need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not connected: for example, if $k=1$ it has two path components, given by the two orientations with which $V$ can be embedded into itself.

In general, it has the homotopy type of $F_k(V; O(n))$ the space of configurations of $k$ particles in $V$ with labels on the orthogonal group, which has $2^k$ path components given by the possible configurations of the orientations.

If you ask for the embedding of each $V$ to be orientation-preserving, then the space is path-connected for $n > 1$ by Tilman's argument (as $SO(n)$ is connected).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  To take the last statement further, if I demand that the embeddings preserve a framing of $V$ do I get a homotopy equivalence to $F_k$ with unlabeled points, and so the highly connected as $n\to\infty$ result?

Comment: Yes, that's right.